# traverse container with multikey

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, traversal

Please find a better title

---

If you know Mathematica I want to do something related to this:

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g, h}};
m[[All, 2]] (* returns: {b, e, g} *)
```

---

Suppose I've some objects and they are arranged on a N-dimensional grid, let say 3D and call the dimensions `x,y,z`. In addition `x,y,z` are also properties of the objects and there is a 1-1 relation between every `(x,y,z)` and the objects.

Now I want to iterate on a container over one direction, keeping the other two properties fixed with an iterator interface for example:

```
Container<MyObject> container;
...
container::iterator it1 = container.begin(undefined, 1, 2);
container::iterator it2 = container.end(undefined, 1, 2);
// now the range [it1, it2] contains all the objects with y=1 and z=2
// ordered by x
```

I have had a look to `boost::multi_index_container` but it seems you cannot fix `y` and `z` in my example.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, what is a good solution?

- More realistic scenario: `x,y,z` are generic type (usually `int`, `string` or `enum`)
- More realistic scenario: I want to add keys (`w`) easily
- More difficult scenario: `MyObject` objects are not sortables (yes, I can use `x,y,z` to sort it)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using an iterator? Wouldn't it be easier to iterate over this inside a `for`?

Comment: yes, because I have a lot of functions taking as input a range of objects in the form `iterator_begin`, `iterator_end`